# Jupyter notebooks HR tag not rendering well

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, amazon-sagemaker

I use Brave browser for my jupyter notebook (not jupyterlab) works under Amazon Sagemaker, but I also use Chrome for my Internet activities, so last week the update symbol appeared on Chrome, so I updated it, and immediately my notebooks on Brave stopped rendering well the following tag `<hr style="border:3px solid black"> </hr>`, which shows a thick straight line that I use to separate blocks of cells in a markdown cell, is now rendered as a thin gray line that is also generated by `---`.

A couple of days after that Chrome update, the update symbol showed on Brave too, so I updated it and nothing happened, the line was still rendered as if it were a `---`.

Has anyone noticed this behaviour and found a solution? Maybe it's because of some change in how the browser renders tags or something?

Note: I opened the same notebooks on JupyterLab (Sagemaker), they are rendered fine there.

Thank you in advance!!

EDIT: I launched a Jupyter Notebook from my computer and it always opens in Chrome, and the `<hr style="border:3px solid black"> </hr>` tag was rendered fine, it seems the problem is with the JNs from Sagemaker.

Comment: Does it work well on Chrome? What versions of the browsers you updated to?

Comment: Chrome: Version 92.0.4515.159 (Official Build) (64-bit), 
Brave: Version 1.28.106 Chromium: 92.0.4515.159 (Official Build) (64-bit).